# Expected distance of drunk walk

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

> A drunk person is in place $x=0$ in time $t=0$. Every second he moves
>   forward one meter in a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ or stays in his
>   place in a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ (his decisions are
>   independent). In addition, every second he can pass out in a
>   probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ (also independently).
>
> Mark: $X$ - the distance he reaches.

A. Find the expected value of $X$.

B. Given he reaches at least 2 meters, find the expected value of $X$.

My solution:

A. $Y$ - number of seconds until he passes out. $Y\sim Geo(\frac{1}{2})$

$X|Y\sim Bin(y,\frac{1}{2})$

Therefore: $E(X) 
=E(E(X|Y))=E(\frac{Y}{2})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot E(Y)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot2=1$

B. $E(X|X\ge2)=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x\cdot P(X|X\ge 2)$

$P(X|X\ge 2)=\frac{P(X,X\ge2)}{P(X\ge2)}$

But I'm stuck at this point. 
Also, is it just $E(x)+2$?

Comment: From observational experience, a few meters, I'd say. But it really depends on the drunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let E be the expected value of the distance after it has moved by 2 meters. Starting from 2,
 • We have a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance of passing out and staying put; from here the distance is $2$ . • We have a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance of not passing out and staying put and the distance then is  E.  • We have a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance of moving forward and not passing out and the distance is $(E+1)$. • We have a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance of moving forward and passing out and the distance is $3$. Thus, $$E = \frac{1}{4}(2) + \frac{1}{4}E + \frac{1}{4}(1 + E) +\frac{1}{4}(3)$$ Solving gives $E = 3$.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand why the distance of moving forward and not passing out is $(E+2)$

Comment: You are right it is (E+1).  Changed it

Comment: Thanks again. May I ask why it is memoryless?

Comment: No, I don't have the answer.

Comment: Memorylessness is a property of random walk which it is.  Secondly, if it is memoryless then the conditional expectation E(X/X>x) = E(X) + x, the proof of which is seen in here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48496/conditional-expectation-of-exponential-random-variable